# Efficient Transformations of LiveData<List> to another LiveData<List>

Tags: android, list, android-room, android-livedata

Consider some generic `@Entity User` stored in a Room db. Some `@Dao` retruns a `LiveData<List<User>>` aka 'dao result'.  I wish to create another *live* list where each element is a transform of the dao result, say

```java
LiveData<List<UserWrapper>>

//UserWrapper needs a User to construct
```

So I write something like

```java
 Transformations.map(daoResult,list -> {

            
            List<UserWrapper> newList=new ArrayList<>(list.size());
            list.forEach(user -> {
               newList.add(new UserWrapper(user));
            });

            return newList;
        });
```

If my understanding of LiveData is correct, the dao result only responds to `List` level changes, say the list is added to, subtracted from etc. and not if the underlying User object  is or its fields are changed.

1. Is this correct?

Say  some changes are made in the db which have made some new records eligible to be in the result set of the underlying dao result's `@Query`

2. Would the `LiveData<List<User>>`, the query result, automatically reflect that? Would the `Transformations.map` carry it forth to `LiveData<List<UserWrapper>>`?

In the above implementation every time the underlying **list** is modified, the map is  creating a new List and reinitializing it which to me seems inefficient and wrong somehow. Why should one have to do the manual checking of of both lists to ensure consitent transformed state?

3. Is there a better way to do this so that there is always a 1-1 correspondence between the `User`s and `UserWrapper`s?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've got the point of your question, but consider my thoughts:

1. When you use LiveData as a query's return type, Room sets for you some kind of callback. So if you use `select * from users ...` in your query, then EACH change to table `users` triggers updating LiveData's value (it's not obvious, so I mean - EACH change, even if some user has been changed that is not in your result list).
2. In theory you can get from the query to table `user` not only `List<User>`, but `List<UserWrapper>` as well. It depends on the `UserWrapper` and `User` structures. For that you should write a query with fields that match to `UserWrapper` fields, or to use [Room's Relations](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Relation).

Comment: so if I have a user in the table and say its name column is changed in the table, the corresponding name field of `User`in my List would automatically be updated without the need for a refetch?

Comment: To be exact - after user's name change in db table, all attached LiveData values will be updated if - LiveData has observer (either with observe() method in activity or with `Transformation.map/switchmap`). So if for example you set user's List to Recyclerview's adapter inside observe() method - you'll see updated name there. And yes, there is no need for refetch LiveData.